# Как сделать быстрый поиск с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Моя регулярка работает медленно. Как ускорить процесс?
Например, у меня есть такой хтмл текст `test1<div>test2</div>`.
Я хочу все что в не div также завернуть в div. Как мне лучше это сделать?

Вот мой пример:

```
// между текстом который перед див и самим дивом вставляю текст ($html$)
.replace(/(<div[^>]*>.*<\/div>)/gi, '($html$)' + '$1')
// беру весь текст перед ($html$), то есть который вне div и заворачиваю в див
.replace(/(.*)\(\$html\$\)/gi, '<div>$1</div>')
// удаляю текст ($html$)
.replace(/\(\$html\$\)/, '')
```

P.S. У меня такой случай, что текст вне дива может быть только в начале.

Comment: А почему вы не сделаете без "регулярки" данную функцию?

Comment: @Yuri как сделать, подскажи? с удовольствием сделаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нам действительно надо завернуть только текст, стоящий перед первым `<div>`, то нам не интересно содержимое `<div>`, достаточно только факта его наличия:

```
.replace(/(.*?)(?=<div[ >])/i, '<div>$1</div>');
```

Возможно без использования регулярок будет работать быстрее (замена в переменной `a`):

```
var pos=a.indexOf('<div');
if(pos>0) a='<div>'+a.substr(0,pos)+'</div>'+a.substr(pos);
```

Comment: да, содержимое не интересно. А если будет два в строке?

Comment: @MagaAndiskiy Два чего ?

Comment: ой, извини, два `div`. К примеру `text without tag <div> test1 </div> <div> test22 </div>`

Comment: @MagaAndiskiy Заменит точно перед первым. Ведь в первых скобках стоит знак вопроса (`.*?`), говорящий о том, что туда должно попасть как можно меньше символов

Comment: при больших данных работает очень медленно. Например у меня изображения в base64

Comment: @MagaAndiskiy максимум, что можно сделать это в первой части попробовать без откатов. но у вас все равно остается самая тяжелая операция, создать новую переменную, скопировать в нее начало строки, вставить `</div>` и скопировать все остальное, по крайней мере такая замена "внутри" может быть произведена только так.

Comment: @MagaAndiskiy Можно попробовать без регулярок, может действительно быстрее будет, но тогда вы не сможете это делать без учета регистра. По крайней мере нам понадобится indexOf которая может искать без учета регистра ... Если `<div>` только маленькими буквами, это конечно облегчит задачу

Comment: все теги маленькими буквами, как сделать без регулярок? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @MagaAndiskiy поправил ответ

Comment: спасибо, проверил. Довольно быстро работает.